# Processing dataframe omits previous row values

Tags: python, pandas

This code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['stop' , '1'], ['a1' , '2'], ['a1' , '3'], ['stop' , '4'], ['a2' , '5'], ['wildcard' , '6']] , columns=['a' , 'b'])

print(df)
```

prints :

```
          a  b
0  stop      1
1  a1        2
2  a1        3
3  stop      4
4  a2        5
5  wildcard  6
```

I'm attempting to create a new dataframe where if stop is encountered then a new row is created that contains a tuple where the value of column 'a' is first element of tuple and 'b' is subsequent element of tuple.  So for df above post transforming the new df df_post structure is :

```
df_post = pd.DataFrame([['stop' , [('a1' , '2') , ('a1' , '3')]] , ['stop' , [('a2' , 5)]]] , columns=['a' , 'b'])

print(df_post)

      a                   b
0  stop  [(a1, 2), (a1, 3)]
1  stop  [(a2, 5)]
```

wildcard is also a stopping condition where if encountered a new row is inserted into df_post as before.

Here is what I have so far :

```
df['stop_loc'] = ( (df['a'] == 'stop') | (df['a'] == 'wildcard') ).cumsum()
df_new = df[(df['a'] != 'stop') & (df['stop_loc'] != df['stop_loc'].max())].groupby('stop_loc').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.a, x.b)))
df_new
```

which renders :

```
stop_loc
1    [(a1, 2), (a1, 3)]
2    [(a2, 5)]         
dtype: object
```

The 'stop' value is not inserted as row. How to modify so that the dataframe produced is

```
      a                   b
0  stop  [(a1, 2), (a1, 3)]
1  stop  [(a2, 5)]
```

instead of :

```
stop_loc
1    [(a1, 2), (a1, 3)]
2    [(a2, 5)]         
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering out the stop rows with `df['a'] != 'stop'`.  Here is an alternative code:

```
# df['stop_loc'] = ( (df['a'] == 'stop') | (df['a'] == 'wildcard') ).cumsum()
df['stop_loc'] = df['a'].isin(['stop', 'wildcard']).cumsum()

def zip_entries(x):
    return list(x.a)[0], list(zip(x.a[1:], x.b[1:]))

df_new = (df[(df['stop_loc'] != df['stop_loc'].max())]
          .groupby('stop_loc')
          .apply(zip_entries)
          .apply(pd.Series))

print(df_new)
#              0                   1
# stop_loc                          
# 1         stop  [(a1, 2), (a1, 3)]
# 2         stop           [(a2, 5)]
```